# Error in boost graph

Tags: c++, boost, point-cloud-library, boost-graph

I am using PCL library and internally it needs boost libraries.

Unfortunately I am getting an error like this. Explicitly I dont refer to any of the boost library but PCL library does.

```
/usr/include/boost/graph/graph_concepts.hpp: In destructor ‘boost::concepts::AdjacencyMatrix<G>::~AdjacencyMatrix()’:
/usr/include/boost/graph/graph_concepts.hpp:368:17: error: missing template arguments before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/boost/graph/graph_concepts.hpp: In member function ‘void boost::concepts::AdjacencyMatrix<G>::const_constraints(const G&)’:
/usr/include/boost/graph/graph_concepts.hpp:372:17: error: missing template arguments before ‘(’ token
```

Comment: Also, you should show lines being referred to

Comment: Ok. I gather point cloud library. It's taking a while to compile on my box (it's only a quad-HT i7 with 32GiB). Let you know when it's done

Comment: point cloud library is compiling without any errors. But when i use a header pcl/registration/icp.h in an program, then the shown error in the question is popping. There is no error when i use other header files.....By I any chance is it an error because of the boost libraries ?

Comment: @Sal why didn't you /mention/ this in your question o.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very strange.

The problem is solved when I moved the header file

`#include<pcl/registration/icp.h>`

to the beginning of all the header files. No error any more and the program executed giving the expected results!

Comment: Good find. Please report to the devs of PCL :) I had just arrived at a succesful compile including just `icp.h`

Comment: I have had problems like this before. They usually stem from forgetting to put a semi-colon in a custom created class header. I would double check any of your headers before mailing the developers. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

Can't reproduce it.

Here's what I did:

- ubuntu 13.10
- kernel 3.11.0-20-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP x86_64
- `sudo apt-get install libeigen3-dev libflann-dev libboost-all-dev cmake build-essential`
- downloaded https://codeload.github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/tar.gz/pcl-1.7.1

Compilation took some time

```
cd /tmp
tar xf ~/Downloads/pcl-pcl-1.7.1.tar.gz 
cd pcl-pcl-1.7.1/
cmake .
time make -sj
```

Output ends with

```
...
Linking CXX executable ../bin/pcl_train_linemod_template
[100%] Built target pcl_train_linemod_template

real    13m55.327s
user    82m49.499s
sys 2m24.611s
```

Pretty impressive. But clearly no compilation errors (http://paste.ubuntu.com/7359651/). I hope you can work out what is different for you.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, one of your program header files has some `#define ZZZ` statement and that macro ZZZ collides with some identifier in Boost. This is why the problem is gone when you move `icp.h` to the first line.

To find out which macro is causing the problem, look carefully at the line you specified: `/usr/include/boost/graph/graph_concepts.hpp:368`. The macro probably replaces or removes one of identifiers on this line or in its vicinity. Good luck.